# android gradle deamon invalid response

Tags: android

Error:Received invalid response from the daemon: 'org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.ForwardInput@6abb1b33' is a result of a type we don't have a strategy to handle. Earlier, 'Build{id=0e61f099-e554-40bb-8282-d5f838838db1.1, currentDir=E:\samrin shaikh\DreamSwaliya}' request was sent to the daemon. Diagnostics: No diagnostics available.
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error. I also had this related error:

> Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I tried to open another project which was working properly before, but saw the same error on that project too. I restarted Android Studio and this time my second project loaded normally. When I got back to my original project it found a tiny error in my **build.gradle** file which was an unexpected character at the beginning of that file. Apparently, I unknowingly made a faulty change in that file.

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3.

Hope this helps.